# Zsh in Cygwin 1.7

Tags: windows, terminal, cygwin, zsh

When starting Zsh as the shell in Cygwin 1.7, I get the escape characters in plain text. When using Zsh with the -l option, this is resolved. Why is this?

[image]

As you can see, the terminal renders the Bash prompt correctly, but the Zsh prompt does not render the prompt as ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: PS1= for bash don't work with zsh, unless they are very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zsh` starts a new interactive shell, `zsh -l` starts a **login** shell.

The main difference between a login shell and any other interactive shell is that a login shell reads different configuration files. For zsh this comes down to:
`/etc/zprofile`, `~/.zprofile`, `/etc/zlogin` and `~/.zlogin`.

The reason why the prompts acts differently is probably due to a setting in one of these files.

For a longer and more detailed explaination, see [chapter 2, section 6](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l6) of this guide.